# How would I go implementing a stacked card-based view?

Tags: ios, swift

Would anyone mind pointing me in the right direction of making a card view just like the one in the image shown below? I've been scouring the internet for over an hour trying to find a tutorial (in Swift) and all I could find was making the illusion of separated cards like [this](https://medium.com/@cwRichardKim/ios-xcode-tutorial-a-card-based-newsfeed-8bedeb7b8df7) and [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76024/swift-table-view-animations-tutorial-drop-cards).

Any help or input would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't be that hard to do this yourself with custom code.

You could also use either a UICollectionView. Getting the look you want with a collection view is doable but would require some customization.

Yet another option is a third party framework like iCarousel (by Nick Lockwoods) iCarousel is very flexible and powerful, and comes with tutorials demonstrating a number of different options.

Comment: I think I'll try the collection view option. The thing is I mainly want to code this myself for the experience rather than relying on a third party framework.